# How to authenticate user with Omniauth-facebook in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, authentication

I have started developing my rails app and an user will login using only facebook i.e. `omniauth-facebook gem`. But now how can i have `user_signed_in?` like method without using devise in my app ?

I want to authenticate user before every action in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  protected
  def authenticate!
     redirect_to root_path unless user_signed_in?
  end
  def user_signed_in?
     !!session[:user_id]
  end
  def current_user
     User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

By placing the methods in ApplicationController you can call them inside any of your controllers. Now, to use them in your views, you have to copy this code into your ApplicationHelper

```
 module ApplicationHelper
     def user_signed_in?
      !!session[:user_id]
     end
     def current_user
        User.find(session[:user_id])
     end
 end
```